# Can't Connect to MySQL Database Through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is probably just a stupid mistake somewhere but i cant connect to mysql.
And it have been bugging me for days now!

Im trying to create a database for a web shop tutorial am doing.
And this is done thru Dreamweaver and cPanel.
Im trying to connect to my mysql database from this code:

-----connect_my_sql.php-----

```
 <?php
$db_host = "hostip";
$db_username = "build";
$db_pass = "*****";
$db_name = "myonlinestore";
$myConnection = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass", "$db_name") or die ("could not connect to mysql".mysql_error());
?>
```

(password and hostip is changed)
Where username is connected to the database and psw is the right one.
And i dont get any error from .mysql_error()

all this is done in a subfolder on my main domain on godaddy.

Have tryed to do a admin page and i cannot connect to my database to use the log in i have created in mysql.
witch is the following code:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<?php

if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Connect to the MySQL database 
    include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person

    $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
             $id = $row["id"];
         }
         $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
         $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
         $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
         header("location: index.php");
         exit();
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

(i removed all the styling in the code)

and all i get is that the information is incorrect, but i have created a admin table and user in my database.
But i cant log on.

All i get from this is that there is some issue when im trying to connect.
and it has to be from my end becouse godaddy cant see any errors or that i cant connect on there logs.

I will be very greatfull if you could help me with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: mysql_query vs mysqli are 2 seperate things. Use mysqli_query instead of mysql_query

Comment: Just a comment on your code.  Why are you not allowing special characters in your password and I hope your db password is longer than 5 char.

Answer (score 4):

You can't connect to database because you opened connection with `mysqli` api and after you use `mysql_query` that actually belongs to `mysql` api and doesn't have any connection to database

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
        //^ here you use the wrong api
```

Just change this with mysqli query command, [**learn more here**](https://www.php.net/mysqli)

Comment: didnt work. still get could not connect to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The top file is called 'connect_my_sql.php'
file being included is 'connect_to_mysql.php";

Also, use 'require_once' since the file is required for the script to function.

Comment: my mistake on that one, its connect_to_mysql.php on both files.
where should i have the once statement ?

Comment: Replace the `include` with `require` because `require is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue. ` http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: thanks! but still have my original problem.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error, even with the changes recommended?

Comment: yes i am. it have to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what the answers of @DoctorDerp and @Fabio, this is wrong too

```
 $myConnection = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass", "$db_name") or die ("could not connect to mysql".mysql_error());
```

remove everything after the or, and then on the line under add an `if` to test connection like so the code become like this

```
$myConnection = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass", "$db_name");
if(!$myConnection){
    die("Cannot connect to database");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use a simpler sign-in script i created.

```
 $dbc=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database") or die ("Error in   Connecting to database");

 $email=$_POST["idamuid"];
 $password=$_POST['idamupassword'];
 $email=htmlspecialchars(mysql_escape_string($email));
 $password=htmlspecialchars(mysql_escape_string($password));




    $query="select member_email from members where member_email='$email'
     and member_password=sha('$password') "; 


    $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);


    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['userid']=$email;
    header("location:index.php");
    mysqli_close($dbc);

    }
    else{

            echo "Login Unsuccessful";
            echo '<p><a href="signin.php">Please Try Again</a></p>';
```

Comment: You're still using the old mysql API for the mysql_escape_string as opposed to mysqli_real_escape_string but there is a much better way of doing this with prepared statements.